# *Highchart* Disable Chart Title and display when Download/Print

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, title

I have a chart with chart title like this: `text: 'Monthly Average Temperature' http://jsfiddle.net/8Luvf7oo/`, and want to ask if it's possible to disable the title of the chart and then when the chart is downloaded/printed, the title will be displayed only in the downloaded/printed picture ? Is it possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

you can define this parameter in exporting, and set the default title to null,like this:

```
    title: {
        text: null
            },
    exporting:{
            chartOptions:{
                title: {
                    text:'Monthly Average Temperature',
                    x: -20
                }
            }
        },
```

this is a [worked demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dRbpOTHcHiBFYhqUdvbQ?p=preview)

Comment: thanks aitnasser, it worked for the downloading function, but not for printing, do you have any idea ?

Comment: For printing use `beforePrint` and `afterPrint`, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.beforePrint).

Comment: @Pawel: I add `this.options = {
                      title: {
                        text: 'aaaa'
                      }
                    };` to the beforePrint function but it seems not working

Comment: Use [`setTitle()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.setTitle). Setting option directly isn't the best idea :)

Comment: I have updated the [worked demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dRbpOTHcHiBFYhqUdvbQ?p=preview) and now it working also for printing

Comment: @aitnasser: I did not see anything change, did you put the wrong demo ? :)
@PawełFus: I put ``setTitle()` and it works, but the new title will be located inside the graph, how can I put it in the most top of the graph ?

Comment: this [worked demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dRbpOTHcHiBFYhqUdvbQ?p=preview) resolve also the problem of title style

Comment: is it possible that I still keep the size of the chart, not resizing but the title still be put at the top of the chart ?

Comment: yes look now at the [worked demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dRbpOTHcHiBFYhqUdvbQ?p=preview)

Comment: The solution it's to resizing

Comment: Works for me too. Latest chrome on W7?

Comment: I dont know why, when I downloaded it, the title works fine when it is at the top of the chart but when I print it, it is inside the chart